# Why the code is calling Get() from ClassB?

Tags: c#, oop

When I call the code lines below, it executes Get() from ClassB.

The object is created as `ClassC`, which as method with `new` keyword. Ideally, it should call `Get()` from `ClassC`.

```
Main()
{
      ClassA obj = new ClassC();
      lbl.Text = obj.Get();
}


public class ClassA
{
  public virtual string Get()
  {
    return "from A";
  }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
  public override string Get()
  {
    return "from B";
  }
}

public class ClassC : ClassB
{
  public new string Get()
  {
    return "from C";
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help me to find the reasons.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-s-the-difference-between-code-override-code-and-code-new-code.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The key is the `new` keyword in the `ClassC`. It sais the compiler to use it if the object is handled as a `ClassC`, to overshadow the original `Get()` function.

If the object is a `ClassA` reference, the `Get()` will be handled as the original `Get()` and thus leading to the overriding `Get()` in `ClassB`.

Comment: use of `new` in this context can occur only when you want a declare a method with a name which is same as the `virtual` method name in the base class and **you dont want to override it**..If you declare such method without new and override keyword,compiler gives **WARNING**..To HIDE the **WARNING** you use `new` keyword

Answer (score 1):

The `ClassC.Get` has a different signature (new string) and missing override, so it does not overrides `ClassA.Get`.

Comment: `new` does not change the *signature* of the method, it's a different type of `override`.

Answer (score 1):

The magic is called virtual dispatch.

`ClassB` overrides the `ClassA` `Get`, which means that system knows that `ClassA` has a descentant that has a different implementation of `Get`. When `Get` is invoked on a reference of type `ClassA`, it will check if the reference is in fact `ClassB`, or a descendant, and execute that code instead.

Of course, this is (kinda-sorta) recursive, so if `ClassB` has any descentants that overrode `Get`, those `Get`'s will get called, etc...

The problem here is that the `Get` defined in `ClassC` is not the same `Get` that is refered in `ClassA` and `ClassB`, but an entirely new method (hence the `new` keyword), that just happens to have the same name.

So when `obj.Get()` is called, the system does not goes as far as `ClassC` but only gets up to `ClassB` and executes that. If you want to have `ClassC.Get()` get executed, you could either change the `new` to an `override`, or try to call it via a `ClassC` reference, like `((ClassC)obj).Get()`

Comment: When I see the type of object at "lbl.Text = obj.Get();", it is of type ClassC, so, when Get() is called it should be from ClassC as the type of object is ClassC. Bit confusing. Any idea?

Comment: Sure. When you see the type of the actual object, you are looking at run-time information, that the compiler simply does not have available. Because C# is (mostly) statically typed language, the decision what to call and how is done at compile-time. If you need the call to happen at runtime, you can always declare the variables as `dynamic` shifting the decision to runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It would call Get() from ClassC only if you wouldn't cast it to ClassA first. 
The last virtual implementation of Get() is Get() from ClassB and it is called when you are calling virtual Get() method from A.

Answer (score 0):

The `new` keyword shadows the inherited method. However, it does so only if the compile time type of the object is of type `ClassC`. In your case, the compile time type is `ClassA` which leads to the usage of the inherited version.

That's one of the reasons why you should think long and hard before shadowing inherited members using the `new` keyword. Depending of the declared type of the variable holding the instance, different methods may be called:

```
ClassA a = new ClassC();
ClassC c = (ClassC)a; // Note, this is the SAME instance as in a
Assert.AreSame(a, c);

Console.WriteLine(a.Get()); // prints "from B"
Console.WriteLine(c.Get()); // prints "from C"
```

Comment: When I see the type of object at "lbl.Text = obj.Get();", it is of type ClassC, so, when Get() is called it should be from ClassC as the type of object is ClassC. Bit confusing. Any idea?

Comment: Not the *runtime* type is relevant, but the *compile* time type of the variable holding the instance. So, if `obj` is declared as `ClassA` or `ClassB` it won't call the method of `ClassC`.

Answer (score 0):

the `new` keyword in this context is a hider..

This is typically used when your **base class** has a virtual method and you want the same name as the **base class** virtual method name **without overriding it**.

If you declare such method in derived class without overriding the base class method and the new keyword,the compiler would generate a **WARNING**

If you don't use `new` modifier the compiler would generate a warning.

new modifier says to compiler that the duplicate member is not an accident and thus the compiler dont show a **WARNING**

Answer (score 0):

You may first have a look at [**Versioning with override and new**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fawty39%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). `ClassA` reference will handle `Get()` from the original class. As this type has been **overriden**, Get() of `ClassB` will be called.

`ClassC` reference will handle `Get()` as the **new** method, so method in `ClassC` will be called

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     ClassA obj = new ClassC(); 
     Console.WriteLine(obj.Get());  // will print out "from B"

     ClassC obj2 = new ClassC(); 
     Console.WriteLine(obj2.Get());  // will print out "from C"
}
```